# Computer does not boot when Galaxy 2 in USB port

Tags: boot

Yesterday Samsung Kies updated my phone to Jelly Beans. After that if I leave my phone plugged in usb port of my Dell Precision, the computer does not boot. It loads the bios, but never goes to the bootloader (Grub) selection screen and the screen remains blank. No hardware beeps or anything. Once I remove the phone, the computer starts fine. The phone did not do that with Ice Cream Sandwich before. This is Rogers version of Jelly Beans. Don't they look the bootloader?
Does somebody know what is the cause?

Comment: Sounds like the Computer was attempting to treat the handset as a removable media and was attempting to boot from it?

Comment: I've gotten that too with other USB devices. I've learned not to try to reboot with anything unusual connected to a USB port.

Answer (score 3):

Change boot sequence of computer from BIOS to make Hard Disk above Removable USB media.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your mobile is treated as a bootable USB mass storage. Pull down the notifications and try disabling USB Mass storage in your phone.